# Popup Menu when clicked intent and getIntent

Tags: android, android-intent, position, popupmenu

I'm trying to display content on another activity using list items with popup menu. So if i click on the popup menu of one of the items it must return/display on the another activity of what the item is being clicked. But my problem is that if i clicked that item with the pop up menu it displays another value. I don't know how to fix this. Any ideas how? Thanks a lot.

[This is the item's popup menu to be clicked](http://postimg.org/image/jekp9nnjj/)

[This is the result when item's popupmenu is clicked.](http://postimg.org/image/g2tu7z791/)

Here's my popupmenu code:

```
public void popup(View v){
        showPopupMenu(v);
    }
    private void showPopupMenu(View v){
        PopupMenu pop = new PopupMenu(CompanyActivity.this, v);
        pop.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,pop.getMenu());

        pop.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

                String album_name = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.album_name)).getText().toString();
                i.putExtra("album_name", album_name);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
            });
        pop.show();
    }
```

Comment: Hard to help with no code whatsoever

Comment: @PedroOliveira please check my popupmenu code

Comment: You will have to use `arg0` to get the current menu item you just clicked

Comment: @PedroOliveira how do i use the arg0?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html